# Lock ribbon button in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, ribbon-button

I am developing a application in VB.NET. The user interface contains a ribbon tab with a few ribbon buttons. On each ribbon button click event, the application will execute a process.

When a process being executed, I want to lock the click event of other ribbon buttons. It means, the user should not be able to pick the other ribbon buttons.
I do not find the lock property for ribbon buttons. To avoid the button getting grey, I do not want to disable the button. please provide your suggestion.

Comment: Create a boolean variable in your form. Set it to false whenever you want to disable the buttons and check at the beginning of each click handler. Abort the handler if false. On a sidenote: I would suggest to disable the buttons. The user should know, when he can click something and when he can't.

Comment: Thanks. But, is it possible to remove the click event of the button?

Comment: Of course. But you should avoid the `Handles` statement in that case and instead use the `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` statements to assign and remove event handlers.